# ImageCache action: How do I set the width as 500px and the height will constrain propotion to width?

Tags: media

I use ***ImageCache Action*** to add watermark and resize image.

How do I set the width as **500px** and the height will constrain propotion to width?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Found solution***
Use "Scale" in Action, Width:500, Heigth:0,
Select "Allow Upscaling"
Then update action.